# Ссылка на срез отличается от ссылки на сам массив

Tags: golang

Прохожу тур по языку *go* и есть вопрос по срезу с [этой страницы](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7)

Модифицировал код, чтобы узнать кое-какие детали:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/rand"

func main() {
    rand.Seed(1)
    primes := [6]int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    x := 0
    y := x + 1 + rand.Intn(2)
    fmt.Println(x, y)
    var s []int = primes[x:y]
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &primes)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &s)
    s[0] = 123
    fmt.Println(primes)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Вывод:

```
0 2
[2 3]
0x104401c0
0x1040a150
[123 3 5 7 11 13]
[123 3]
```

Сначала проверил, можно ли делать динамические срезы. Код показывает, что можно. Потом решил узнать как срезы реализованы. И тут вопрос: почему ссылки на массивы `s` и `primes` отличаются, в то время как если изменить значение массива `s`, то меняется и `primes`? В *go*, получается, не чистые массивы, а что-то типа структур с дополнительной информацией?

P.S. Можно как-то узнать расстояние между ссылками в `go` (`&s - &primes` - не работает)?

Comment: срез ссылается на элементы массива, поэтому нет ничего странного, что изменение одного влияет на другой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Слайс это структура, одним из элементов которой является ссылка на массив https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go primes у вас массив, а s - slice со ссылкой на исходный массив primes. При изменении s - меняются элементы нижележащего массива, так что пока s ссылается на primes - в primes тоже будут видны изменения.
2. Адресная арифметика доступна только в unsafe-коде https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/  в общем случае она запрещена, т.е. без unsafe-режима узнать расстояние в памяти между объектами не получится.